# Can MATLAB define a 'block' limiting a scope like C++ can?

Tags: matlab

For C++ case:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    cout << a << endl;
    { /* Start of a block limiting a scope */
        int a = 2;
        int b = 3;
        cout << a << endl;
    } /* End of a block */
    cout << a << endl;
    // cout << b << endl; /* This stops compilaiton */
    return 0;
}
```

it shows a result:

```
1
2
1
```

My question is, **does MATLAB have a functionality or keyword similar to this?**

Comment: The short answer is no. What are you trying to accomplish? MATLAB only really has local scope within a function (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html)

Comment: What I want: I don't want to mess up a workspace with a temporary variable (it seems dirty and sometimes it might change a workspace variable). MATLAB requires one file per function. I want in-file, inline scoping.

Comment: You can define multiple (non-nested) functions per file and they each would have their own local scope. [Local functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html)

Comment: Thank you @Suever, when is the `local functions` introduced first? R2016b?

Comment: A local function *within a script* was just introduced in 2016b but having multiple functions in a *function file* has been around since at least 2006

Comment: If the workspace is contaminated with temporary variables you write too long functions. Try to add local helper functions below the public function. Think in terms of that each function should have one well defined task. Apart from this AFAIK Matlab does not support local scoping. Each function will get its own workspace. This not exactly equivalent to the c++ scope either, since for, while, and if statements does not get an own workspace either. Try for (k = 1:12), l = k+1; end; disp(l);